My Laravel project does not load and just keeps loading
I have a very big problem
I have a Laravel project
The problem is that no matter what I do, the pages don't open for me and they just keep loading and nothing happens.
I tried all kinds of methods.
From checking the Laravel log to errors on the Apache side, checking DNS to the closing of my port address, from deleting the project vendor to creating a new project and transferring my information, but no page is loaded for me and only the Google spinner spins for me.
I cleared the caches of my Laravel, even the files that I had added, but the problem was not solved at all. There is no problem in other projects, but this cannot be solved in any way. I had to start coding from the beginning: please help me.

Have you opened up your browser's developer console to see if there's any hints there? Do the requests in the Network tab complete or does it keep loading specific items?

Check your laravel.log file for any bugs and issue with your views and routes.
Or
try to debug manually from routes defined, the controller, the view and the data fetching and display.

i have done all them , but...
